# $pull on mongodb nested array not removing object

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have an object structured like this:

```
{ '_id': '123456'
  'searches': [{ 
                  '_id': '123'
                  'keyword_search': 'fender, stratocaster',
                  'company': 'guitar center',
                  'location': 'chicago'
                },

               { 
                  '_id': '1762'
                  'keyword_search': 'gibson, les paul',
                  'company': 'sam ash',
                  'location': 'new york city'
                }]
 }
```

I'm using pymongo, and I want to be able to delete one of the objects from searches, and I'm using the following command which is coming back without modifying anything.

```
database.update( {"_id": '123456' }, { '$pull': { 'searches': { '_id': '1762' } } } )
```

I've went through multiple examples, and I can't seem to see what it is I'm doing wrong here as to why mongodb can't find the correct document to update.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: First thing to check is whether the type of input in filter part `{"_id": 123456 }` matches with the type of `_id` field in DB ! Use a find query with the filter to check whether if a doc is being returned or not..

Comment: In your example, the document has _id `'123456'` but the update is looking for `123456`.   Since mongodb query operators are type-sensitive, that doesn't match.